# How to instantiate a UIViewController from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios-universal-links

I have the following setup in my app:
[image: Storyboard setup]

There is a container view which holds 3 view controllers (A, B and C). I'm able to switch from A, B or C by swiping left or right. Both A or B contain their own collection view. If I tap on any cell in the collection view inside A or B, the PlayerVC (named Player in the pic above ^^) launches and a video begins to play using `AVPlayer`.

The problem is:

- This app is able to share `Universal Links` so when a user taps on a `universal link`, it takes them directly to the app, launches the `PlayerVC`, and begins playing a video. The problem is how do I initialize the other view controllers if the user is taken directly to the `PlayerVC` if they tap on a `universal link`? Or how to get to `PlayerVC` from `app delegate`?

Here are some scenarios:

- If the user is taken directly to the `PlayerVC`, then if they dismiss the `PlayerVC` the app crashes.
- If the app is already launched but in background mode, let's say the user was in `view controller B`, then when the user taps on a `universal link`, how do I go from `view controller B` to `PlayerVC`?

This is the delegate method in the `app delegate` that gets called when a `universal link` is tapped by a user (please notice the `HELP` comment):

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // Other App Delegate methods.....

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        // 1) Make sure the passed `user activity` has expected characteristics.
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            return false
        }

        // HELP: I need to get to `PlayerVC` from here?

        return true

        // If we can't do the above we default to opening the page in safari
    }
}
```

Note:
Our app is running iOS 10. We are using Apple's new api's for Universal Links: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is:
>
> This app is able to share Universal Links so when a user taps on a
>   universal link, it takes them directly to the app, launches the
>   PlayerVC, and begins playing a video. The problem is how do I
>   initialize the other view controllers if the user is taken directly to
>   the PlayerVC if they tap on a universal link? Or how to get to
>   PlayerVC from app delegate?

For this problem, you'd need to first instantiate the container and its child view controllers, then you can show the PlayerVC

> If the user is taken directly to the PlayerVC, then if they dismiss
>   the PlayerVC the app crashes.

With the implementation that I told you, it shouldn't crash. There is always gonna be a container controller instantiated

> If the app is already launched but in background mode, let's say the
>   user was in view controller B, then when the user taps on a universal
>   link, how do I go from view controller B to PlayerVC?

You can store in your AppDelegate a global variable of your container controller. With this you can access to controller B. Then you can call

```
container.present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. How exactly would I go about instantiating the container and its child view controllers based on my issue? Can you provide a code sample? Thanks